# Access Input mask shifts my numbers

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, input-mask

I am not familiar with access input mask. Here is my mask `999\+999` as `___+___`, my point here is that the user may enter a digit or not before the "+" so if I want `11+222` as `_11+222` it will be formatted to `112+22` like  it 'is shifting always to the left, I tried `###\+###` but in vain same result.

Any explanation will be appreciated

Comment: if you're ok with leading zeros you could use 000+000

Comment: ' 0 ' : entry required !! it is not my case

Comment: Is that an error, or is that supposed to mean you're not ok with leading zeros??  I'm not entirely sure that that means....

Comment: I want to keep the entered order even if the user enter less than 3 digits before ' + '

Comment: When ever you use a mask that data will be stored as text. Text is always left oriented in a text box. which is why your results come out as 112+22 instead of 11+222. There are a couple ways to achieve this but input masking may not be one of them, unless you're ok with some type of place holder before or after the +. Have you considered instead having two seperate boxes for the first half and second half of your number, then using code to put them together.

Comment: My field here is a kilometer point Km+m , I will see if I can find an alternative format, thank you Gene for the clarification